# MKMapView addAnnotation for zero coordinates

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapkit

MKMapView addAnnotation for zero coordinates: (0, 0) ignored.

Android Google Map adds Marker/Annotation for zero coordinates.

Is it Apple's bug, or missed something?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Code is not very simple and I see now it is most probably my mistake.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MKMapView addAnnotation for zero coordinates: (0, 0) **NOT** ignored.

[image]

```
    let annotation2 = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0,0)
    annotation2.title = "title2"
    annotation2.subtitle = "Do2 any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. "
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation2)
```